# When I used python3.4's easygui CodeBox to display some characters, the format was in disorder

Tags: python, python-3.x, easygui

I am trying to use codebox to display a calendar in easygui in python3.4

My code is as follows

```
    import easygui,calendar
    cal7 = calendar.month(2018, 7)
    easygui.codebox(cal7,"2018.7")
```

But its display results are as follows

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8j4s.png

You can see,these numbers are out of order.

But something interesting,I run this code with wine's python 3.4, the display is correct.

My OS:Linux mint 17.3(mate)

python version:3.4.3

easygui version: (0.98.1)

How should I solve this problem? Thans for your help

Answer (score 0):

I used your code in `python 3.8` and it worked fine.

Maybe your `python` and `easygui` had some bugs.

Just download `python 3.8` and newest `easygui`.

Used:

Windows 10 Pro with python 3.8 and easygui 0.98.1